# Unable to display CampingListItem component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trailhead

I'm a bit lost on how to troubleshoot this issue.  I've completed the Attributes and Expressions trailhead, ie passed the challenged however I'm unable to display the component, campingListItem, in my HarnessApp.  I get this error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application. An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 33374234-34842 (-1501584897)

.... code removed

When I remove the `<c:campingListItem />` tag things load just fine.  It doesn't matter where I put this component, here or in the `campingList` component the same error comes up.

So I'm at a bit lost on what's going on, and why I'm unable to load this component.

---

code of the component, CampingListItem:

```
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>

... code removed per forum guidelines

</aura:component>
```

Comment: OK so after some playing I've figured out if I removed the 'required' attribute option the component loads.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you specified a required attribute but you are not providing it in your markup:

You said you are declaring your component like this:

```
<c:campingListItem />
```

But the component has a required attribute which you are not defining above. You should have something like

```
<c:campingListItem item="{!v.item}" />
```

Where `v.item` is of type `Camping_Item__c`.